# Creating an specific type of meta-algorithm

Tags: matlab, algorithm

I need to create a program able to create an algorithm to Matlab. For instance, in this program, I want to give it an integer n>0 and make it create a Matlab algorithm with the following code:

```
u1 = sdpvar(1);
u2 = sdpvar(1);
u3 = sdpvar(1);
...
un = sdpvar(1);
```

Does someone knows how to do this in Matlab?

Regards,